# Unable to pass a variable value to a stored procedure in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

When executing an SSIS package, the following error appears:

> [OLE DB Source [83]] Error: The SQL command requires a parameter named
>   "@Sales_person", which is not found in the parameter mapping.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: OLE DB Source failed the pre-execute phase and
>   returned error code 0xC0207014.

Below is the screenshot of my OLE DB Source editor
[image]

[image]

[image]

I do see Param direction tab in Set Query parameters, how is that used? In my case will I be using `Input` or `Output` or `InputOutput`

Comment: `Error: OLE DB Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC0207014.` It sounds like if you apply delay validation to the properties of the data flow task that may solve your issue. You can also make the expression User::SALES constantly evaluate itself so it appears present by the flow, this should allow you to get past the pre-execute phase when it's doing a validation check.

Comment: DelayValidation is True in the Data Flow task

Comment: @mehtat_90 take a look at my answer and give me a reply if it is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching i didn't find a solution for this issue that worked for me. Ther are many suggestions like adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` before the execute command. Below some related links:

- http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Data+Flow+Task+(SSIS)/117370/
- http://www.ssistalk.com/2007/10/10/ssis-stored-procedures-and-the-ole-db-source/

**You can do a workaround**

Declare a SSIS variable *(assuming `@[User::Query]`)*

Set `@[User::Query]` property `EvaluateAsExpression` = True and use the following expression

```
"EXEC [dbo].[GetDales_Person_data] " + @[User::Sales]
```

if `@[User::Sales]` is a string use the following

```
"EXEC [dbo].[GetDales_Person_data] '" + @[User::Sales] + "'"
```

Then In `OLEDB Source` use `SQL Command from variable` and select `@[User::Query]`

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Data+Flow+Task+(SSIS)/117370/ helped me to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the mapping. See image and source below to make corrections, you should set it to:

```
Exec [dbo].[GetSales_Person_Data] @Sales_person = ?
```

[image]

[Source - geek with blogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx)

Comment: it throws an error 'The EXEC SQL construct or statement is not supported.'

Comment: What if you use `[dbo].[GetSales_Person_Data] @Sales_person = ?` . You may have to leave out the exec. [Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/479c6c00-7cb4-47cc-92fc-9ea9d503e7ee/the-exec-sql-construct-or-statement-is-not-supported?forum=sqlreportingservices)

Comment: Same Error [OLE DB Source [83]] Error: The SQL command requires a parameter named "@Sales_person", which is not found in the parameter mapping.

Comment: What if you set your expression `User::Sales` to `True` under `EvaluateAsExpression`? [Source](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesn/archive/2008/08/20/60692.aspx)

Comment: Please attribute your sources: It appears that you just copied straight from here: http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the source is already attributed to it below the screen shot. .

Comment: Oh sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with mapping parameters directly into the EXEC statement.

One way you can get around this is to use:

```
DECLARE @SalesPerson int = ? -- or whatever datatype

EXEC [dbo].[GetSales_Person_Data] @SalesPerson
```