# The SQL command requires a parameter named "@SessionID", which is not found in the parameter mapping

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, oledb, etl

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure via SSIS

> Error: 0xC0207014 at PO Header, OLE DB Source [59]: The SQL command
>   requires a parameter named "@SessionID", which is not found in the
>   parameter mapping.

[image]

But as you can see below, the variables are populated, I have mapped the parameters.
So what's going on?

[image]

- MS SQL 2014
- MS Visual Studio 2015

Comment: On weird occasions SSIS bugs out like this, try recreating the source box as Hadi suggested.

Comment: Also just write.. Exec dbo.porg_po_header ?, ? (or what ever schema you have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshots, you have mapped variables to parameters. Then just try to delete and recreate the OLE DB Source.

- [The SQL command requires a parameter, which is not found in the parameter mapping](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/79a9476b-fe8e-42a5-99b5-6f5bac4d2b3c/the-sql-command-requires-a-parameter-which-is-not-found-in-the-parameter-mapping?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

If it still throwing an error, then use expressions instead of parameters. You can refer to the following link for more information:

- [Unable to pass a variable value to a stored procedure in ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619211/unable-to-pass-a-variable-value-to-a-stored-procedure-in-ssis)

Comment: Thank you, that helped.  I had to change the Parameters to /@SessionID and /@PORG_id in the mapping.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and even having Visual Studio crash on me. I found that rather than using parameter index of 0,1, 2... I used named parameters in my OLEDB connect and this resolved my error. You must include the @ in the parameter name and they must match your sql stored procedure parameter names.

For example instead of [0] and [1] name parameters @StartDate and @EndDate